# Android Pjsip Video Call: Green screen before actual window renderred

Tags: android, voip, pjsip, pjsua2

I am implementing Video Call using the Pjsip library and 80% it worked well.

I am facing one issue like when I initiate a video call, it first displays a green screen like below and then renders actual video streaming.

[image]

I am not getting any hint over here.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Is that the background colour of your activity?

Comment: Maybe the preview is drawn on the SurfaceView which already has the green color

Comment: You can show front camera until rendering is not ready as WhatsApp does!

Comment: Did you start transmit or using vid_out_auto_transmit?

Comment: @SonPham Ues it is already true when I register my user.

Comment: In my case, i start transmit and send key frame. I had the green color before I started transmit.

Comment: @SonPham have you used PjCamera class?

Comment: @AanalMehta i have used pjsua for iOS.

Comment: @SonPham oh Okay.

Comment: @AanalMehta, this is example for android https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android. I hope it helpful for you.

Comment: @SonPham Alright. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Hey @SonPham, as you've developed in iOS, can you help me in this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57917496/ios-pjsip-incoming-video-call-crash