# iOS Pjsip: Incoming Video Call Crash

Tags: ios, pjsip, pjsua2

When I recieve incoming Video Call, my application got crashed.

Here is the code for Video Configuration:

```
acc_cfg.vid_in_auto_show = 1;
acc_cfg.vid_out_auto_transmit = 1;
acc_cfg.vid_wnd_flags = PJMEDIA_VID_DEV_WND_BORDER.rawValue | PJMEDIA_VID_DEV_WND_RESIZABLE.rawValue;
acc_cfg.vid_cap_dev = PJMEDIA_VID_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_DEV.rawValue;
acc_cfg.vid_rend_dev = PJMEDIA_VID_DEFAULT_RENDER_DEV.rawValue;
```

Here is the code I used when I accept the call:

```
call_opt.aud_cnt = 1;
call_opt.vid_cnt = self.isVideoPossible(callId: id)
print("video count", call_opt.vid_cnt)
pjsua_call_answer2(id, &call_opt, 200, nil, nil) // 200 PJSIP_SC_OK
```

I have gone thorugh the logs and found that camera opened and then suddenly my app got crashed.

```
19:05:14.563           pjsua_call.c !Answering call 0: code=200
19:05:14.563        sip_transport.c  ..Tx data Response msg 180/INVITE/cseq=102 (tdta0x117146aa8) cloned
19:05:14.564         inv0x11614bea8  ..SDP negotiation done: Success
19:05:14.564           pjsua_call.c  ...Call 0: remote NAT type is 0 (Unknown)
19:05:14.564          pjsua_media.c  ...Call 0: updating media..
19:05:14.565          pjsua_media.c  .....Media stream call00:0 is destroyed
19:05:14.565            pjsua_aud.c  ....Audio channel update..
19:05:14.566        strm0x1171d4628  .....VAD temporarily disabled
19:05:14.574                  rtp.c  .....pjmedia_rtp_session_init: ses=0x116226318, default_pt=0, ssrc=0x271afe9c
19:05:14.574                  rtp.c  .....pjmedia_rtp_session_init: ses=0x1160f6010, default_pt=0, ssrc=0x271afe9c
19:05:14.576               stream.c  .....Stream strm0x1171d4628 created
19:05:14.576        strm0x1171d4628  .....Encoder stream started
19:05:14.576        strm0x1171d4628  .....Decoder stream started
19:05:14.578             resample.c  .....resample created: high qualiy, small filter, in/out rate=8000/16000
19:05:14.578             resample.c  .....resample created: high qualiy, small filter, in/out rate=16000/8000
19:05:14.578          pjsua_media.c  ....Audio updated, stream #0: PCMU (sendrecv)
19:05:14.580          pjsua_media.c  .....Media stream call00:1 is destroyed
19:05:14.580            pjsua_vid.c  ....Video channel update..
19:05:14.581          vid_toolbox.m  .....Opening codec..
19:05:14.684                  rtp.c  .....pjmedia_rtp_session_init: ses=0x11622838c, default_pt=97, ssrc=0x5d41c7d2
19:05:14.685      vstdec0x116227c28  .....Decoding channel created 720x1280 I420<-H264 22/1(~22)fps
19:05:14.685                  rtp.c  .....pjmedia_rtp_session_init: ses=0x11622795c, default_pt=97, ssrc=0x5d41c7d2
19:05:14.685      vstenc0x116227c28  .....Encoding channel created 720x1280 I420->H264 15/1(~15)fps
19:05:14.688           vid_stream.c  .....Video stream vstrm0x116227c28 created
19:05:14.688      vstenc0x116227c28  .....Encoder stream started
19:05:14.688      vstdec0x116227c28  .....Decoder stream started
19:05:14.688            pjsua_vid.c  .....Setting up RX..
19:05:14.688            pjsua_vid.c  ......Creating video window: type=stream, cap_id=-1, rend_id=0
19:05:14.688             vid_port.c  .......Opening device OpenGL renderer [OpenGL] for render: format=I420, size=720x1280 @22:1 fps
19:05:15.568       ios_opengl_dev.c  .......iOS OpenGL ES renderer successfully created
19:05:15.568             vid_port.c  .......Device OpenGL renderer [OpenGL] opened: format=BGRA, size=720x1280 @22:1 fps
19:05:15.574             vid_conf.c  .......Added port 0 (OpenGL renderer)
19:05:15.574            pjsua_vid.c  .......stream window id 0 created for cap_dev=-1 rend_dev=0
19:05:15.574            pjsua_vid.c  .......Window 0 created
19:05:15.576             vid_conf.c  ......Added port 1 (vstdec0x116227c28)
19:05:15.576             vid_conf.c  ......Updating render state for port id 0 (1 sources)..
19:05:15.576             vid_conf.c  ......This port only has single source with matched format & size, no conversion needed
19:05:15.577             vid_conf.c  ......Port 1 (vstdec0x116227c28) transmitting to port 0 (OpenGL renderer)
19:05:15.577       ios_opengl_dev.c  ......Starting ios opengl stream
19:05:15.577            pjsua_vid.c  .....Setting up TX..
19:05:15.580             vid_conf.c  ......Added port 2 (vstenc0x116227c28)
19:05:15.580            pjsua_vid.c  ......Creating video window: type=preview, cap_id=2, rend_id=0
19:05:15.580             vid_port.c  .......Opening device Front Camera [AVF] for capture: format=I420, size=720x1280 @15:1 fps
19:05:15.650             vid_util.c  .......Orientation converter created: 1280x720 to 720x408, maintain aspect ratio=yes
19:05:15.650           darwin_dev.m  .......Video capture orientation set to 1
19:05:15.650             vid_port.c  .......Device Front Camera [AVF] opened: format=I420, size=720x1280 @15:1 fps
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I did not see anything wrong in this log. Did you rotate camera? or rotate Video stream?

Comment: Yes. I did rotate camera by 90 degree but that code is written in call_media_state. But app got crashed once I answer call and the last log I could see in my console it this only.

Comment: Did you try to start transmit after call func "pjsua_call_answer2"?

Comment: Hey @SonPham, yes I tried. At the end I used call_answer method without auto_transmit true at start and it worked.

Comment: your application still crashed or worked.

Comment: @SonPham We created separate threads and it worked.

Comment: Aanal Mehta I had a problem about re-connect. When network disconnected and reconnected, my video view has freeze and can not do anything

Comment: @SonPham I am still facing same problem and I think that is because of threading. Because sometimes it worked and sometimes it doesn't. :\ That's quite annoying.